# How to get the inscribed rectangle in a canvas clip

Tags: java, android, android-canvas

In android canvas, I've defined a clipping area with many shapes (a rectangle and 2 circles). I want to get the inscribed rectangle defined by the clipping area.

Canvas has a method called `getClipBounds()` which gives me the circumscribed rectangle, how do I get the inscribed rectangle instead?

[image]

Edit: Here's some info on how the original shape is made:

1. First add a clip for the big circle with `Region.Op.INTERSECT`
2. Then add a clip for a vertical rectangle with `Region.Op.INTERSECT`
3. Then add a clip for a smaller circle with `Region.Op.DIFFERENCE`

Comment: Is that original shape made by cutting a white circle out of a red one?

Comment: yeah it is. I'll edit the question to add a bit more details on how the original shape is made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be determined mathematically if you know the radius & center of both circles.

Find two the intersection points of circles with the getClipBounds() rectangle.
-The the second highest intersection point between the red circle and the getClipBounds() rectangle holds the upper y coordinate of the rectangle.
-The high intersection point between the white circle and the getClipBounds() rectangle holds the lower y coordinate of the rectangle.
-The x bounds are already given by the getClipBounds() rectangle.

You can construct your three shapes from there.

Comment: Ok cool, this approach works. I'll use it for now. The one problem with this approach though is that it relies on the assumption that my shape is a rectangle with 2 circles. Although this is true, (so there's technically no real issue here) I'd prefer a more general solution that allows for clips made out of any shapes. More extensible for the future.

Comment: Can you access the image on a pixel by pixel basis? If so I have a more general solution if you'd like.

Comment: I can draw the image onto a Bitmap and grab the pixels from there, I'm not too sure the efficiency of this (I'm guessing it's probably a bit slow), but I'd like to hear the general solution. Thanks!

Comment: This is a paper on finding the largest inscribed rectangle in any convex polygon. Probably not what you had in mind, but if you want the "general" solution, it's going to be pretty involved. [http://www.mpi-inf.mpg.de/~jeschmid/public/Knauer2012.pdf]. You can ignore most of the math stuff and distill the significant algorithm from it (end of the paper).